# Origin of the term "sinc" function

Tags: ho.history-overview, fourier-analysis, terminology, signal-analysis

Is the sinc function [defined here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html), really a short form of "sinus cardinalis" as [proposed by Wikipedia](//hsm.stackexchange.com/a/7476)? This information is deleted now but it existed some time ago. Even if we search Google Books for this term, a lot of new books call sinc as *sinus cardinalis* without even bothering to check Woodward's original paper. The origin of sinc is attributed to Peter Woodward's work dating 1952, but he never mentions *sinus cardinalis* anywhere. This term is not listed in any etymological dictionary of mathematics and even unabridged Oxford English Dictionary.

What is meant by cardinal sine, if we assume whoever tried to rationalize the term, thought of it as a meaningful term?

Here is the paragraph from Woodward, P. M.; Davies, I. L. (March 1952). "Information theory and inverse probability in telecommunication" (PDF). Proceedings of the IEE - Part III: Radio and Communication Engineering. 99 (58): 37–44. doi:10.1049/pi-3.1952.0011

Thanks.

[image: Original Image]

**Woodward in his book writes:"Probability and Information Theory, with Applications to Radar" pg 29.**

[image: sinc function]

Comment: In French it's called "sinus cardinal".

Comment: ... since at least G. Battail ([1964](//link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03011244), p. 128) and J. Lochard, *Introduction et application de certains résultats de l’analyse à la théorie des signaux*, L’Onde électrique **42** (1962) 709–[714](//books.google.com/books?id=Xn9GAQAAIAAJ&q=%22fonction+fondamentale+employée%22).

Comment: I think we should search something around 1952 or earlier.  Most of the work on communications/signal processing was done in English, as far as I can guess.

Comment: You may also post history questions at the [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It was already asked by someone else and the answer was a cut-paste Wiki answer.

Comment: HSM question: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/7474/1697 and MSE question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830070/history-of-latin-sinus-cardinalis

Comment: See [MSE question 299912](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/299912) "What is the etymology of the 'since function'?".

Comment: @Somos, it is the same cut-paste Wikipedia answer which I have posted in the question.

Comment: Actually "sinc" would have been a strange notation for the English name (which would have suggested "csin"), but for the Latine name it sounds natural.

Comment: "Sinus cardinal" doesn't sound very Latin. Maybe "sinus cardinalis"? (Edit: yep, as per F. Ziegler's answer)

Comment: @YCor I’m guessing the French phrase originates in what [Colonel Lochard](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNxkHpNGOAY) is fluffily [reviewing](//google.com/books?id=Xn9GAQAAIAAJ&q=Ville+Oswald): “La théorie des signaux dits à spectre limité, basés sur ce développement a été particulièrement développée en France par [Ville](http://www.jehps.net/juin2009.html) et [Oswald](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=AIHP_1953__13_4_245_0) (principalement dans leurs articles publiés dans « [Câbles et Transmissions](//www.worldcat.org/oclc/637544226) »).”

Comment: Other possibility, maybe likelier from the timeline: Woodward meant no name for  $\mathrm{sinc}$, but *his readers (or even translator) retrofitted one* when his book came out in French ([1960](//www.worldcat.org/oclc/20587175)).

Comment: Did you get a chance to read the French version and does it have the sinc = sinus cardinalis? There is no online version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While irruption of *cardinal* in this context must somehow relate to Whittaker’s — also unexplained — use of the word (to name the functions subject to his sampling theorem), it seems far less clear that Woodward’s $“\mathrm c”$ had anything to do with it. AFAICT, that whole notion originated in this ambiguous (and/or misread) statement of Higgins ([1996](//zbmath.org/?q=an:0872.94010), p. [4](//google.com/books?id=vUwFTCXK_QcC&pg=PA4&dq=sinus+cardinalis)):

> **Definition 1.2**$$
> \operatorname{sinc}v:=
> \begin{cases}
> \dfrac{\sin\pi v}{\pi v},&\quad v\ne0,\\
> 1,&\quad v=0.
> \end{cases}
> \tag1
> $$
>   The name $“\operatorname{sinc}”$ <sup>1</sup> is common in the engineering literature, and we shall make much use of it from now on.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>1</sup> The name is usually held to be short for the Latin ***sinus cardinalis***. It was introduced by Woodward ([1953](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=58912), p. 29), although it is not certain whether this is the earliest occurrence.

Now this just conflates talk about a **notation** ($\operatorname{sinc}$) with talk about a purportedly related **name** for $(1)$. Whereas, not only does Woodward (as you noted) nowhere write “cardinal” or even cite Whittaker, in fact hardly *anyone* before 1996 seems to have called $(1)$ any name at all:

`Year:            notation:   name: 
 Woodward & Davies            1952 (p. 41)     sinc        — 
 Woodward                     1953 (p. 29)     sinc        — 
 Jagerman & Fogel             1956 (p. 143)    —           cardinal series kernel 
 Nathan                       1956 (p. 788)    sinc        — 
 Bracewell                    1957 (p. 69)     sinc        — 
 Raabe                        1958 (p. 181)    sinc        — 
 Ragazzini & Franklin         1958 (p. 31)     —           cardinal hold response 
 Linden & Abramson            1960 (p. 26)     sinc        — 
 Helms & Thomas               1962 (p. 179)    sinc        — 
 Lochard                      1962 (p. 714)    ?           sinus cardinal 
 Petersen & Middleton         1962 (p. 303)    —           cardinal function 
 Battail                      1964 (p. 128)    sinc        sinus cardinal 
 Bracewell                    1965 (p. 62)     sinc        — 
 Detape                       1965 (p. 9)      —           sinus cardinal 
 Burdic                       1968 (p. 48)     sinc        — 
 Goodman                      1968 (p. 14)     sinc        — 
 Robaux & Roizen-Dossier      1970 (p. 733)    sinc        — 
 McNamee, Stenger & Whitney   1971 (p. 142)    sinc        — 
 Oswald                       1975 (p. 65)     —           sinus cardinal 
 Lannes & Pérez               1983 (p. 163)    sinc        sinus cardinal 
 Schempp                      1983 (p. 213)    sinc        sinus cardinalis 
 De Coulon                    1984 (p. 23)     sinc        sinus cardinal 
 Usher                        1984 (p. 98)     sinc        — 
 Léna                         1986 (p. 111)    sinc        sinus cardinal 
 Schempp                      1986 (p. 193)    sinc        sinus cardinalis 
 Butzer, Splettstößer & Stens 1988 (p. 2)      sinc        — 
 Stenger                      1993 (p. vi)     sinc        —`

The above are all I found who used a special notation and/or name for $(1)$ — please add any that I missed. Attendant observations:

- Even the sinc **notation** was rather rare among the scores who published about the sampling theorem. (250+ papers in engineering journals over 1950–1975, according to Butzer ([1983](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=85h:94007), p. [186](http://jmre.dlut.edu.cn/en/ch/reader/view_abstract.aspx?file_no=19830149)).) Bracewell 1965 is apparently the first who attributed it to Woodward.
- Of those who used it, only five (that I could find) concurrently used the **name** *sinus cardinal(is)*, mostly after 1983. (Lochard 1962 might too, and would be interesting to get your hands on.)
- Stenger 1993 says that Whittaker’s series “reappeared (...) in the important papers of Hartley, Nyquist and Shannon, who illustrated [their] role in communication theory. The term “sinc function” (...) was first defined and used in these papers, where sinc is defined by” $(1)$. I couldn’t corroborate the last sentence.
- Butzer & al. ([2011](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2012a:94003), p. [655](http://sweet.ua.pt/pjf/t_subject_sampling.html)<sup>12</sup>) write that “The sinc function (...) had been defined by Raabe’s teacher [Küpfmüller](http://ict.open.ac.uk/classics/)”. However, it is unclear just what they mean to say he “defined” — thing, name, notation? Incidentally this paper, or the slides by Stanković & al. ([2013](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jta/computing-history-material/remarks%20for%20sampling%20theorem.pdf)), should dispel any preconception on what language things happened in.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming that the origin of sinc is mythical and it is rather modern. I will see if we can add more.

Comment: at least one author is not blindly following sinus cardinalis story. He writes "Was das "c" beduetedt, habe durch den Hinweis eines aufmerksamen Lesers inzwischen gelernt: Es beduetet "sinus cardinalis". Das "c" ist aber schon bei der Definition der komplimentaren Error-Funktion erfc(x)=1-erf(x) "verbraucht" worden". In the new edition, he removed it and writes " I don't know what c stands for"  https://books.google.com/books?id=OOrywEnrhwoC&pg=PA37&dq=%22sinus+cardinalis%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimyeGbsNnkAhUB7awKHWGOBJAQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22sinus%20cardinalis%22&f=false

Answer (score 10):

The Wikipedia page for the [Shannon-Whittaker reconstruction formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula?wprov=sfla1) states that Whittaker used the term "cardinal series" for the reconstruction formula
$$
f(t) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} f(n)\mathrm{sinc}((t-nT)/T)
$$
as early as 1915. This may explain the name "cardinal sine".

Comment: I checked the Whitaker's Original Paper, Whittaker, E. T. (1915). XVIII.—On the Functions which are represented by the Expansions of the Interpolation-Theory. Proceedings of the Royal Society of Edinburgh, 35, 181–194. doi:10.1017/s0370164600017806, he never uses the term cardinal sine or sinus cardinalis. He does introduce the term cardinal. I think the question is now who associated the term sinus cardinalis to the Whitaker's relation.

Comment: When an edit to the question included a link to a similar question on hsm.stackexchange, I realized that my answer is basically the same answer as the accepted answer over there…